# How to code the swipe to delete to allow user to only delete their Parse data in iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I have an app with a shared photo stream and I need the user to only be able to swipe and delete their own photo items...my basic code setup works to delete with swipe, but I can't figure out the best way to code so that it verifies first that the PFUser matches as the owner of the PFOject before allowing for swipe and delete

```
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{   
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{   PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    }];
}
```

Grazie,

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you have to manually refresh the table because you have not refreshed the table. Add the code as follows

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    // Remove the row from data model
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        // Add refresh control & reload the tableView. 
        [self refreshControl];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I figured it out the proper way and it seems to work    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath :(PFUser *)user {
if (![user.objectId isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
        return YES;
}
return NO;
}

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            [self loadObjects];
        }
    }];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off ,in your photo class you need to have a pointer to the user who owns the photo.

Now in your table view controller you have an array of your PFObjects that you called objects.

So to allow the user to delete only his/her photos you could do something like this.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
PFObject* photoObject=self.objects[indexPath.row];
PFUser* owner=photoObject[@"owner"];
[owner fetchIfNeeded];

if ([owner.objectId isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
    return YES;
}
else return NO;
 }
```

However a better way to do this is to have a custom class and make your table view controller model that class as the following:

```
@interface MyPhoto : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property UIImage* photo;
@property PFObject* parseObject;
@property BOOL iOwnThisPhoto;

//Class method to fetch the photo stream from parse and return an array of MyPhoto*
+(NSArray*)fetchStream;
@end
```

In my table view controller I would have something like this

```
@interface PhotoStreamVC ()
//Private property
@property NSMutableArray* photos;
@end

@implementation PhotoStreamVC
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [super viewDidLoad];
 //Do background fetch
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchPhotoStream) withObject:nil];
  }
  -(void)fetchPhotoStream
  {
    self.photos=[MyPhoto fetchStream];
    //Reload table view from the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];

     }); 

  }


  - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    MyPhoto* photo=self.photoStream[indexPath.row];
    return photo.iOwnThisPhoto;

    }
  @end
```